# Extract pixel values in raster stack using shp

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, extract-by-mask

I am using the following code to extract mean pixel values over an area represented by a polygon:

```
mean<-lapply(S2_stack, FUN=function (S2_stack) {data.frame(mean=extract(S2_stack, polygons2, fun=mean))})
```

Where:

```
> S2_stack
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 1454, 1595, 2319130, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : 744490, 760440, 4773400, 4787940  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      : Subset_S2_MSIL2A_20180511T100029_MCI, Subset_S2_MSIL2A_20180710T100029_MCI, Subset_S2_MSIL2A_20180906T101021_MCI, Subset_S2_MSIL2A_20181115T101251_MCI
```

and `polygons2`:

```
polygons2 <- readOGR('/path/Insitu_poly.shp')
```

with:

```
> class(polygons2)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

When I try to run my code I am getting the following error:

```
 Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ?extract? for signature ?"numeric", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"?
```

Not sure why. It seems `extract` needs a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and as far as I know, it should run

Any idea?

Comment: @Aaron same error using `mean<-lapply(S2_stack, FUN=function (S2_stack) {data.frame(mean=raster::extract(S2_stack, polygons2, fun=mean))})` Not sure how to proceed. Chekcint the documentation, I dont see a problem in the class of `polygons2`

Comment: Use simply `extract(S2_stack, polygons2, fun=mean, df = T)`. Don't use `lapply`

Comment: I think the problem is with the raster, not the polygons. I've never used lapply when extracting from a raster stack. Maybe try just doing `mean <- extract(S2_stack, polygons2, fun=mean)`

Comment: Your stack has four bands. Do you want the average in each band separately? Or over all bands? `lapply(1:4, FUN=function (i) {raster::extract(S2_stack[[i]], polygons2, fun=mean)})` maybe?

Comment: Using the code without `lapply` worked. However, I do not get completley why as I am providing a list (of rasters) and a funciton to be applied. Please add the comment as an answer and I ll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the correct way to proceed in this case is simply to do

```
mean <- extract(S2_stack, polygons2, fun=mean)
```

as said in the comments, however, if you want to pass your stack in `lapply` you have to `unstack` it first.

```
mean<-lapply(unstack(S2_stack), FUN=function (S2_stack) 
{data.frame(mean=extract(S2_stack, 
polygons2, fun=mean))})
```

Comment: You do not have to unstak the data first, simply define an iterator in lapply, `lapply(1:nlayers(r), FUN=function (i) {raster::extract(r[[i]], p, fun=mean)})` But, using lapply is completely unnecessary and I would highly recommend using a different package entirely. The `exact_extract` function in the exactextractr package far outperforms `raster::extract` and benchmarks are quite notable for multiband data. The is also the idea of migrating to the terra package which will eventually replace raster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the `exactextractr` package instead of the `extract` function of the `raster` package which is extremely slow. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
if (!require("raster")) install.packages("raster")
if (!require("rgdal")) install.packages("rgdal")
if (!require("exactextractr")) install.packages("exactextractr")

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(exactextractr)
})
```

I assume two variables loaded. `img` is a RasterStack with several layers and `shp` is a ESRI Shapefile containing polygons. This shapefile contains a field called `class` with the land cover. You can load this variables using: `img <- raster::stack('file.tif')` and `shp <- rgdal::readOGR('file.shp')`.

```
# extract pixel values on a list of data.frames where
# length(ls.df) == number of polygons of the ESRI Shapefile
ls.df <- exact_extract(img, shp, include_cols="class", progress=TRUE)
# filter only full pixel (coverage_fraction==1)
for(i in 1:length(ls.df)){
ls.df[[i]] <- ls.df[[i]][ls.df[[i]]$coverage_fraction == 1,]
}
# create a single data.frame containing all the pixel values
df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(ls.df)){
df <- rbind(df, ls.df[[i]])
}
```

The `exact_extract` function computes the coverave fraction of each pixel covered by the polygon. You remove this information using as follow:

```
# remove coverage_fraction column
df$coverage_fraction <- NULL
```

You can learn more about this package here: https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr